# How do I install “Perl/Tk Debugger” on Windows 7?

Tags: perl, module, installation

Trying to install the "[Perl/Tk Debugger](http://ptkdb.sourceforge.net/)" on Windows 7 -- and for the life of me I'm unable to figure out what I need to do to install and run this application..

The requirements appear to be:

- [Perl](http://www.perl.org/get.html) 5.004 or above
- [Tk](http://cpan.perl.org/modules/by-category/08_User_Interfaces/Tk/)800.021 or above

I've got Perl 5.12.2 (from ActiveState) installed; confirmed by going to the Windows commandline and entering "perl -v".

What I have no idea about is the "Tk800.021" requirement; meaning if it's already present, and if not, what to do.

---

**Error on "ppm inst Ptkdb"**

```
C:\Users\User>ppm inst Ptkdb
ppm inst failed: Can't find any package that provides Ptkdb

C:\Users\User>ppm inst C:\Devel-ptkdb-1.221.tar.gz
ppm inst failed: Can't find any package that provides C:\Devel-ptkdb-1.221.tar.gz
```

Comment: It might be superfluous now, but EPIC (Perl debugger using Eclipse) is worth a look: http://www.epic-ide.org/

Comment: I am sad to say that this either is no longer working or just does not work for me. My original intent was to get a current version of Perl-Tk on my Windows 7 PC of course the debugger would have been next. Any more ideas?

Comment: Your answer is a comment, not an answer. My suggestion would be to post a new question on Stack Overflow clearly stating your goals, the environment your using, versions of software, error messages, etc. -- or post a comment below [bvr's answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5154924/471255), though bvr was last on 19 hours ago, so it might be awhile before you get help. As for me, I'm not in the position to provide any help, though if you post a question, I'll still take a look at it just in case I notice something. Cheers!

Comment: Also, "It might be superfluous now, but EPIC (Perl debugger using Eclipse) is worth a look: [epic-ide.org](http://epic-ide.org)" -- from the [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154879/how-do-i-install-perl-tk-debugger-on-windows-7/10483825#comment5789012_5154879) might be of use too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running on command-line the ppm (perl package manager) supplied with ActiveState like this:

```
ppm inst Tk
ppm inst Devel-Ptkdb
```

First installs most current Tk (version 804.029 in my case), second the debugger itself. If both commands run successfully (on my machine they did), you should be able to run the debugger with:

```
perl -d:Ptkdb your_script.pl
```

Comment: @bvr: +1 Thanks, "ppm inst Tk" worked like a charm -- "ppm inst Ptkdb" gave me an error, and since I've this is only the second ppm inst I've ever done, really not sure what's wrong -- any suggestion, posted the WIN-CMD and resulting errors in my questions description under <Error on "ppm inst Ptkdb"> -- again, thanks!!

Comment: @blunders - Oh, I put wrong command. Please use `ppm inst Devel-Ptkdb`.

Comment: @bvr: +1 thanks, but that returns the same sort of error, that being "ppm inst Devel-Ptkdb" returns "ppm inst failed: Can't find any package that provides Devel-Ptkdb"

Comment: @bvr: Figured it out "ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/Devel-ptkdb.ppd" -- thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @blunders - this is weird. According to [this page](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Devel-ptkdb/) it is not available for 5.10 nor 5.12, however I was able to install it this way few weeks ago on 5.12. Looks like it is still available from bribes (use `ppm repo add http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/` prior `ppm inst Devel-Ptkdb`)

Comment: @blunders - other option is to download the package from sourceforge and put `ptkdb.pm` file into your `perl\site\lib\Devel` directory. There is nothing else needed.

Comment: @bvr: +2 Great, thank you for all the additional info -- huge help!! Got it running, very happy -- again, thanks!